# Removing duplicate dates in two arrays using lodash/fp

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

I'm trying to take a more functional approach to displaying data and having trouble removing duplicate items from an array. What I'm trying to achieve is removing and/or merge items which are of the same date.

I've tried using the `_.uniqBy` but it just returns the list untouched it's because it's a date object and therefore.

`new Date(2018, 4, 7) === new Date(2018, 4, 7)
//false
new Date(2018, 4, 7) == new Date(2018, 4, 7)
//false`

is there a way to deepMatch using `uniqBy` or another method of merging or removing duplicates in a functional approach.

note: objects/functions have been simplified to the problem.

```js
const items = [{date: new Date(2018, 4, 7), wellbeing: 50}];
const days = [{date: new Date(2018, 4, 7)}, {date: new Date(2018, 4, 8)}];
const Row = (item) => item; // not real map just mock

function mapToRow(data) {
   return _.pipe([
    sortByDate,
    _.uniqBy('date'),
    _.map(Row)
  ])(data)
}
function sortByDate(array) {
  return array.sort((a, b) => {
    a = new Date(a.date);
    b = new Date(b.date);
    return a < b ? -1 : a > b ? 1 : 0;
  });
}

console.log(mapToRow(days.concat(items)));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lodash@4(lodash.min.js+lodash.fp.min.js"></script>
```

can use lib such as moment

> // expected outcome
>
> `[{date: new Date(2018, 4, 7), wellbeing: 50}, {date: new Date(2018, 4, 8)}]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`_.unionWith()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#unionWith), and check for equality using [`_.isEqual()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#isEqual):

```js
const items = [{date: new Date(2018, 4, 7), wellbeing: 50}];
const days = [{date: new Date(2018, 4, 7)}, {date: new Date(2018, 4, 8)}];

const result = _.unionWith(
  (arrVal, othVal) => _.isEqual(arrVal.date, othVal.date),
  items,
  days
);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lodash@4(lodash.min.js+lodash.fp.min.js"></script>
```

With just ES6, you can [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) both arrays to a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), and then [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) the [`Map.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/values) back to array:

```js
const items = [{date: new Date(2018, 4, 7), wellbeing: 50}];
const days = [{date: new Date(2018, 4, 7)}, {date: new Date(2018, 4, 8)}];

const result = [...items.concat(days)
  .reduce((r, o) => {
    const time = o.date.getTime();
    return r.set(time, { ...r.get(time), ...o });
  }, new Map())
  .values()];
  
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can group by date and then use map with `Object.assign` to merge:

```js
const items = [{date: new Date(2018, 4, 7), wellbeing: 50}];
const days = [{date: new Date(2018, 4, 7)}, {date: new Date(2018, 4, 8)}];
const Row = (item) => item; // not real map just mock

function mapToRow(data) {
   return _.pipe([
    sortByDate,
    _.groupBy('date'),
    _.map(xs => Object.assign({}, ...xs)),
    _.map(Row)
  ])(data)
}
function sortByDate(array) {
  return array.sort((a, b) => {
    a = new Date(a.date);
    b = new Date(b.date);
    return a < b ? -1 : a > b ? 1 : 0;
  });
}

console.log(mapToRow(days.concat(items)));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lodash@4(lodash.min.js+lodash.fp.min.js"></script>
```